# Desire stuck in Boot Loop After mod install

Tags: htc-desire, boot, boot-loop

I installed an Audio Mod 'BeatsAudio' through clockworkmod recovery on my HTC Desire. After i rebooted it just keeps looping the boot logo over and over. I have tried removing the battery, sim and SD card, and also no luck there.

I've also tried wiping the data and cache partition but that doesn't help. I can get in the HBOOT menu but unrevoked doesn't seem to recognize my phone.  I have tried ropening a stock boot rom to see if that would install it but it tells me its not compatible with my 64Bit OS.

I have no idea what else to do.

Comment: Most probably your kernel doesn't fit your device (CDMA vs GSM? or sth. else). Are you S-OFF (changed your hboot)? Can you enter the bootloader? Remove the battery, hold vol-down then press pwr until you see the bootloader and select 'recovery' to install  CyanogenMod (for the [GSM](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?type=stable&device=bravo) or [CDMA](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?type=stable&device=bravoc) model). Then unpack boot.img in the cm*.zip and flash it via 'fastboot flash boot boot.img' (also part of the SDK) . This should give you a regular CyanogenMod 7.2 Gingerbread.

Comment: GSM i assume. I'm S-ON, I dont have a SD reader, so i'm not quite sure how i'll transfer a rom onto the card. Can i just insall CyanogenMod straight from Clockworkmod recovery, should i unpack the img out the zip or just copy the zip file and install that? I'm not fully clear on this. @ce4

**To be clear this wasnt A MOD/ROM it was just a zip file that changed the audio settings. I was already rooted with unrevoked, just after i installed this through clockworkmod it started looping**

Comment: Well, the .zip can contain not only settings, you had to look at the contents to be sure. You have CWM at hand, so you just can flash another ROM using the recovery. Install the SDK and fastboot+adb commands. You can transfer a firmware.zip file with "adb push rom.zip /sdcard" when you run the CWM (be sure the SD card is "mounted" in CWM before). Then follow cyanogenmod's full update guide for the GSM: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/HTC_Desire_(GSM):_Full_Update_Guide

Comment: Did you wipe Dalvik cache?

Answer (score 2):

You installed Mod to **system**, so you need to reflash ROM from recovery.

Erase user data (hard reset) will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

wipe dalvik cache after wiping cache
reboot and wait a while

Comment: The question says "I've also tried wiping the data and cache partition but that doesn't help."

Comment: @onik cache != Dalvik cache. There's the "app cache", and there's the "Dalvik cache". Though I'm not sure whether the latter is not always part of the `/data` partition (on some ROMs it is -- but I don't know whether this is a general rule).

Comment: @Izzy At least in Samsung recovery mode wiping cache wipes both, I just assumed it was the same in other recovery modes.

Comment: No prob -- above info was "just in case" ;)